# Is there a way to fix language tags in github repos?

Tags: ios, objective-c, github

I have about [**a dozen example projects on github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC?tab=repositories), all written in Objective-C, and all but 1 of them for iOS.

github tags projects based on the programming language it **THINKS** they use. Four of my projects are tagged as being written in "M", One in Matlab, and one has a blank language field. So github's success is about 50%.

Is there some way to correct the language tagging that github does?

Answer (score 0):

That really odd behavior, Github using the [linguist ruby gem](https://github.com/github/linguist) to detect language statistics.. As far as i can tell this is a known issue that been reported see issue [1033](https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/1033) for more details about Objective-c code getting mixed with Matlab

Comment: Just notice you also posted that issue!!